# Change values of duplicate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:
[image]

I want to remove duplicate values in first three columns to have the following table:
[image]

How can I do that? I tried several solutions given on this site but not successful.

Comment: This is best done in the application layer rather than in the database.  The resulting table does not represent an unordered set, because the rows with no values for the first three columns need to be in the right position.

Comment: yes, I think it's the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated sub query to simulate row_number, from there a case expression can be used.

```
select
  case when rn = 1 then title else '' end as title,
  case when rn = 1 then matter else '' end as matter
 -- ...
from (
  select *
    , (select count(*) from tbl as t2 
       where t2.title = t1.title
        and t2.date <= t1.date) as rn
  from tbl as t1
) as t
```